# How can i update or change in array using PHP

Tags: php

I need to update the property `accessories` of this JSON

```json
{
  id: "1",
  name: "TEST",
  accessories: [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
  ]
}
```

How can I add `4` or change `3` to `4` to the `accessories` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Decode JSON to PHP object
$arrr = json_decode('{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "TEST",
  "accessories": [
        1,
        2,
        3
  ]
}');

$old_value  = 3;    // The value you want to change
$new_value1 = 4;    // The value you want to change it to
$new_value2 = 100;  // A new value you want to insert into the array

$array_key = array_search($old_value, $arrr->accessories);  // Get array key of old value
$arrr->accessories[$array_key] = $new_value1;               // Update array with value

$arrr->accessories[] = $new_value2;                         // Add extra value to array

echo json_encode($arrr);             // Re-encode and print results

// Output: {"id":"1","name":"TEST","accessories":[1,2,4,100]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) as approach:

```
<?php
$json = json_decode('{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "TEST",
  "accessories": [
        1,
        2,
        3
  ]
}', true);

$json['accessories'] = array_map(
    function($el) {
        return $el == 3 ? 4 : $el;
    },
    
    $json['accessories']
);

print_r($json);
```

You can test the solution on [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=91610da1bd8a73e860a4a6633b4d4908&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)